# xargs or tail gives error with spaces in directory names

Tags: bash, find, tail, xargs

I have a directory structure

```
Dir 1
Dir 2
Dir 3
```

, so each of the directory names contains a space.

Each directory contains the file `batch_output.txt`. Each of these files starts with a header line and then the data on the next lines.

I want to **append these data files, and the header one time at the top** (so the header should only be extracted from the first file, and not repeatedly) . The command

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f
```

returns the paths of the `batch_output.txt` files just fine, but my attempt to append the data by means of the command

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2
```

gives me the errors

```
tail: cannot open ‘./Dir’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘1/batch_output.txt’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘./Dir’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘2/batch_output.txt’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘./Dir’ for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open ‘3/batch_output.txt’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

I think tail has a problem with the spaces in the directory names.

Under the condition that I have to retain the spaces in the directory names, how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-print0` option with `-0` option in `xargs`:

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 tail -n +2
```

As per `man find`:

```
-print0
  This primary always evaluates to true. It prints the pathname of the current file 
  to standard output, followed  by an ASCII NUL character (character code 0).
```

Comment: Almost works. The data is appended just fine, but the first header is missing. I want to keep the header the first time, but not repeat it afterwards.  

Besides that, I find the description of the `-print0` argument a bit unclear. Why does it solve the problem with the spaces in the directory names, in comparison with the command without the `-print0`. And what does the `-0` argument for `xargs` do exactly?

Comment: Rather than terminating each filename by newline it terminates it by ASCII 0 or `\0`. `xargs -0` reads null terminated input data.

Comment: Do read `man xargs` and section about `-0` that says: **`-0      Change xargs to expect NUL (``\0'') characters as separators, instead of spaces and newlines.  This is expected
             to be used in concert with the -print0 function in find(1).`**

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-exec` argument to `find`:

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f -exec tail -n +2 {} \;
```

If you want to put the output into a new file, just redirect it:

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f -exec tail -n +2 {} \; > /path/to/outfile
```

Comment: Almost works. The data is appended just fine, but the first header is missing. I want to keep the header the first time, but not repeat it afterwards.

Comment: In that case I would probably recommend echoing the heading line to the output file separately and appending the results of the `find` command with `>> /path/to/outfile`

Answer (score 0):

It's `tail` that's not getting a single quoted filename. Use the `-I` argument for xargs:

```
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f | xargs -I X tail -n +2 X
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following script works sufficiently.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
clear

# Extract first line from the first hit by 'find'.
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f -print0 -quit | xargs -0 -n 1 head -n 1 > output.txt

# Append all the data after the first line.
find . -name batch_output.txt -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 tail -n +2 >> output.txt
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution I provided in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31698310/548225). You should accept the answer rather than taking a provided solution and posting another answer based on that.

Comment: @anubhava Hmmm.... not exactly. Your answer does not include the extraction of the header, so I decided to post a more complete answer ;). Anyways, I'm grateful for your help and it's certainly not my intention to withhold any credits from you. If you want, I can certainly accept your answer. Let me know ;). Thanks again!

Comment: See main point of my answer was use of `-print0` in `find` and `-0` in `xargs` since you're getting those errors and that's what your comments also suggested. I just reused same `xargs` command you placed in question assuming that's working for you. You could just leave a comment suggesting you want more head/tail combinations and I would have edited  my answer.